# BigQuery how to get total count per month?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get the total count per month of the current or last year how can I do this? I tried extracting the month or year from the CURRENT_DATE variable but that didn't work.

I don't know if I should use date_trunc or extract. I get syntax errors all the time. I use standard SQL syntax not legacy in BigQuery.

```
SELECT
  COUNT (*)
FROM
  `mytable`
extract(month from current_date) as grpmonth
WHERE
  test = 12
GROUP BY grpmonth
```

I want something like this:

```
2020  Count
----------
Jan   1125
Feb   3308
...
Dec   2043



2021  Count
-----------
Jan   544
Feb   107
...
Dec   232
```

Some errors I got:

```
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword EXTRACT at
```

Comment: Move extract(month from current_date) as grpmonth to after count(), ? Although since you haven't shown us what you want I'm only guessing

Comment: I edited my post so you can see what I want

Comment: Your title says total by month but your desired output is by year and month..

Answer (score 0):

You write the wrong SQL syntax. You should put the extract in the select section.

```
SELECT 
    extract(year from _date) as _year, 
    extract(month from _date) as _month,
    data_source.result
from
 UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', '2021-12-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as _date
left join (
    SELECT
        COUNT (*) as result,
        extract(month from current_date) as grpmonth,
        extract(year from current_date) as grpyear
    FROM
        `mytable`
    WHERE
        test = 12
    GROUP BY grpmonth, grpyear
) as data_source on grpyear = extract(year from _date) and _month = extract(month from _date)
```

You can change the year range by yourself.

Comment: Thanks now the error is gone but I still dont get the expected result. Now I get the total count of the 12 months together like this:

f0_  :    123123       grpmonth: 12 


I want per month

Comment: I update the answer. You could try it.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion. It seems that I doens't recognize _year and _month as variables at the last line. I get the following error: Unrecognized name: _year; Did you mean grpyear? at [19:31

Comment: Oh yes, I correct the SQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

> get the total count per month of the current or last year

Consider below approach

```
select 
  extract(year from date_col) year,
  extract(month from date_col) month,
  count(*) total
from your_table
where extract(year from date_col) > extract(year from current_date) - 2 
group by year, month
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestion. I only get one row with month 12 as result and a count but I also want the other months in the result as seperate rows. What is date_col in this case because I dont use it?

Comment: `date_col` is whatever column you have in your table (`your_table`) that holds the date. the query in my answer returns one row per each month/year! if you are using that query as is  - this is what you should get. unless  you are using extra where clause filtering only month 12! if still dies not work - see [ How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a syntax error. This should work:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT (*), EXTRACT(MONTH from current_date) as grpmonth
 FROM `mytable`
WHERE 
  test = 12
GROUP BY grpmonth
ORDER BY grpmonth;
```